Previously level chair rocks — wood movement?
I made my first stick chair:

On a Monday, I levelled the legs and then glued the uppercarriage. My shop floor is all pitted, so I used what I assumed to be a flat piece of 15 mm (5/8 in) plywood as a reference for levelling.
Next day, I brought the chair home and discovered that it was rocking by about 1 mm (1/16 in) on two diagonally opposed legs. This happened on large tiles (flat), in any orientation. I was surprised, but assumed that either the plywood was not flat, or that I knocked something out of alignment when bashing on the arms and sticks with a mallet.
On Saturday, the rocking remained, so I trimmed the offending two legs with a block plane. The chair stopped rocking and I started putting the finish on (several coats of shellac).
However, on Sunday evening the chair started rocking again! On the other two legs. It’s as if they had expanded before trimming and then shrank again (or the untouched legs had shrank and now expanded). I’m very frustrated as it seems like I shouldn’t have intervened.
How can this happen? Even though I suspect wood movement, and beech is not considered a stable wood, I am not sure how radial or tangential movement can contribute to this. As a corollary, if it is wood movement, is my best bet to finish finishing, move the chair to its final location and wait for it to acclimate before doing anything else?

Joint strength: I am fairly certain this is not caused by the legs moving in their joints. That’s because when I press or sit on the chair, the legs flex a little and the rocking disappears — and comes back exactly as before with the pressure removed.
Climate: My workshop is an unheated/uninsulated garage. Even though I’ve brought the chair home, it’s been mostly on the balcony — a similar environment. I might have left it indoors with the balcony door closed for a few hours before discovering the rocking again.

Edit: it seems to be level again :/ Either I am hallucinating, or it moved again, or I have some floor sections that are uneven in a specific way that made me think it was off.

Nice chair.  I don't have a suggestion for a permanent fix.  I'd apply finish to the chair then stick a small scrap of wood about 1-2mm thick under the appropriate legs in some situations.  There are some situations, such as indoor use on a laminate or hardwood floor that call for an alternative, even if you don't have a wobble.  Those hard wood legs can mark a hardwood or laminate floor so I always apply something to the bottom of hard wood legs as protection if the chair is used in that environment and it's there you can made adjustment for wobble.

Thanks! I do have laminate floors and was planning to apply felt pads. Should I look for ones of different thickness? Or maybe pad them with a few layers of double-sides tape?

I use felt pads on my wooden chairs.  Actually, I bought a half yard piece of a berber like (cheap) carpet with a rubberized backing.  I use contact cement between the rubberized backing and the wood chair bottom.  I use a scissors to cut an appropriate shape piece of the carpet, some square, some round.  I'd stay away from double sided tape.  Tape usually looses it's grip if wet.  One slip of a glass from a dinning room table could take out tape.  Remember it's not just a slip on the floor, something spilled on a chair leg is going to drip down that leg.

Oh, I would not have thought of that! If you were to adjust for wobble at this stage, how would you control the thickness of the padding?

I'd contact cement a slice of wood between the chair leg bottom and the pad.

First off, great job on the chair! Any chair made is something to be congratulated but yours looks to be a very tidy job so kudos! "How can this happen?" Well for a start, you weren't comparing like for like — two different floors which you didn't compare for flat or level, so..... "I am not sure how radial or tangential movement can contribute to this." This is perhaps an insight into why elm is often preferred as a seat material. Your rock may have nothing to do with movement as it's commonly referred to, but instead warping. Doesn't take more than a smidge, and this is beech as you say.

[contd] However the rock may have nothing at all to do with the wood, it could be entirely about the floors so you have to rule that out first. (Which your edit, that I only just spotted, may have confirmed LOL) "It’s as if they had expanded before trimming and then shrank again (or the untouched legs had shrank and now expanded)." This doesn't happen. Movement along the length is considered so small as to be irrelevant pretty much across the board.

Thank you for the kind words. I have to give a lot of credit to The Stick Chair Book which is an excellent manual. Despite the edit, I think my question still stands because I find it hard to believe that the plywood panel was out of flat diagonally. And the initial rocking was observed on many surfaces, including concrete, tile, and the elevator floor. Your suggestion of the seat warping makes sense and I am happy to leave it at that :) Next time (3 chairs to go…) I will pay attention and measure things before/after to see if I can prove this theory.

I am aware of the elm/ash combo for seat/legs, as well as pine/oak etc (my test stick stool had a pine seat and beech legs, but being three-legged it side-stepped the problem anyway, pun intended). I just really like the look of beech+shellac and it makes me feel a part of the European woodworking tradition :) So I am willing to overlook its flaws.

"and the elevator floor" That's a particularly useful additional detail I feel. Although rocking on a variety of floors already suggests it's not about the floor but in the chair, the floors of elevators while they might not be level should be flat (co-planar) which is the minimum needed. "Next time (3 chairs to go…) I will pay attention and measure things before/after to see if I can prove this theory." Beyond measuring in the conventional sense, simply putting a straightedge with level on top (or long level) across various axes of the seat might tell you if it's changing shape slightly.

"I just really like the look of beech+shellac" You're not alone! One good thing about choosing to finish in shellac that you might not be aware of, shellac is actually particularly good at stopping transfer of water vapour (despite not being excellent at stopping liquid water, confusing I know). So your incidental choice of finish has already given you a leg up — pardon the pun — on helping to stabilise the beech.

“shellac is actually particularly good at stopping transfer of water vapour” I did read about that in Flexner’s book. But I don’t think I am taking advantage of that because I did not finish the underside of the seat :D

I’m afraid I’ve now confirmed that the piece of plywood I was using to level the chair was not flat. I’ve levelled a second chair on it and it came out with the same exact rocking, observed immediately on the shop floor (consistently, despite the said floor being uneven).
I’ve also confirmed that while I have the same large tiles outside on the balcony floor and inside right next to it, the inside ones are not coplanar. That explains my “hallucination”.
That said, I think the seat warping, as suggested by @Graphus, is entirely plausible, given how much I’ve seen beech stock warp in my shop.
And felt/carpet pads, as suggested by @quill seem to eliminate or dampen any minor rocking.
